# Mysql stored procedure outer cursor fails to loop

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, cursor

Hi I have a nested cursor with three levels on it...

```
        DECLARE campaign_csr CURSOR FOR SELECT cid FROM tempCampaign; 
        DECLARE date_csr CURSOR FOR SELECT header,ranges FROM tempDate ORDER BY id; 
        DECLARE level_csr CURSOR FOR SELECT 1st,2nd,3rd FROM tempDispoLevels ORDER BY 1st,2nd; 
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_done := TRUE; 
      OPEN campaign_csr; 
           campaign_loop:LOOP 
           FETCH campaign_csr INTO xcid; 
            IF v_done THEN 
                 CLOSE campaign_csr; 
                 LEAVE campaign_loop; 
             END IF; 
select "1";
            OPEN date_csr; 
                date_loop: LOOP 
                FETCH date_csr INTO xheader,xranges; 
                 IF v_done THEN 
                 SET v_done := FALSE;
                     CLOSE date_csr; 
                    LEAVE date_loop; 
                END IF; 
select "2";
                       OPEN level_csr; 
                        level_loop: LOOP 
                        FETCH level_csr INTO x1level,x2level,x3level; 
                         IF v_done THEN 
                             SET v_done := FALSE; 
                             CLOSE level_csr; 
                            LEAVE level_loop; 
                         END IF;
select "3";
              END LOOP level_loop;
       END LOOP date_loop;
  END LOOP campaign_loop;
```

the problem is the outer loop (which in this case campaign_loop) doesn't read all records. Is there any way around this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discover a work around on this: The added variables are for looping the outside cursor until to the last row.

1. Declare 3 more v_done variable

   ```
   DECLARE v_done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE; //this is the original
   DECLARE v_done1 BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE; //added
   DECLARE v_done2 BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE; //added
   DECLARE v_done3 BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;//added
   ```
2. Keep this line:

   `DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_done := TRUE;`
3. Change every declaration of cursor:

> ```
>   OPEN campaign_csr;
>   campaign_loop:LOOP
>   FETCH campaign_csr INTO xcid; 
>         IF v_done THEN 
>              CLOSE campaign_csr; 
>              LEAVE campaign_loop; 
>          END IF;
> ```

into:

> ```
> OPEN campaign_csr; 
>            campaign_loop:LOOP 
>            FETCH campaign_csr INTO xcid; 
>            SET v_done1 := v_done;
>             IF v_done1 THEN 
>             SET v_done := FALSE; 
>                  CLOSE campaign_csr; 
>                  LEAVE campaign_loop; 
>              END IF;
> ```

This code works for me.

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `yourDatabase`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `yourProcedure`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `yourProcedure`()
BEGIN 
        DECLARE xcid INT;
        DECLARE xcid2 INT;
        DECLARE xcid3 INT;
        DECLARE v_done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE; 
        DECLARE v_done1 BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE; 
        DECLARE v_done2 BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE; 
        DECLARE v_done3 BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE; 
        DECLARE campaign_csr CURSOR FOR SELECT column FROM yourTable; 
        DECLARE date_csr CURSOR FOR SELECT column FROM yourTable2; 
        DECLARE level_csr CURSOR FOR SELECT column FROM yourTable3; 
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_done := TRUE; 

        OPEN campaign_csr; 
             campaign_loop:LOOP 
             FETCH campaign_csr INTO xcid; 
             SET v_done1 := v_done;
             IF v_done1 THEN 
                SET v_done := FALSE; 
                CLOSE campaign_csr; 
                LEAVE campaign_loop; 
             END IF; 

                select "1";

             OPEN date_csr; 
                  date_loop: LOOP 
                  FETCH date_csr INTO xcid2; 
              SET v_done2 := v_done;
              IF v_done2 THEN 
                 SET v_done := FALSE; 
                     CLOSE date_csr; 
                     LEAVE date_loop; 
                  END IF;

                  select "2";

                  OPEN level_csr; 
                       level_loop: LOOP 
                       FETCH level_csr INTO xcid2; 
                   SET v_done3 := v_done;
                   IF v_done3 THEN 
                   SET v_done := FALSE; 
                               CLOSE level_csr; 
                               LEAVE level_loop; 
                           END IF; 

                  select "3";

                  END LOOP level_loop;
              END LOOP date_loop;
         END LOOP campaign_loop;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Your "solution", although it works, is illogical and a poor one because it adds lots of useless code. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You *know* each outer loop has **not** finished when you process an inner loop (otherwise you wouldn't be processing the inner loop), so simply reset `v_done` after each  inner loop:

```
SET v_done := FALSE;
```

That's all you need to do.

Don't create a boolean variable for each cursor and copy the value; logically they can only ever be `true`!